# Javascript regular expression to extract text from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
[lorem]{lorem;ipsum;solor;sit;amet}[ipsum]<i>Lorem</i> ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet
```

What I want is an object that contains the following:

```
{lorem: "{lorem;ipsum;solor;sit;amet}", ipsum: "<i>Lorem</i> ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet"}
```

How would my regular expression look? Is there any way to get the inverse of this?

```
/\[\w+\]/g
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the inverse of [`/\[\w+\]/g`](http://regex101.com/r/fC8gN3), just use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.):

```
var string = '[lorem]{lorem;ipsum;solor;sit;amet}[ipsum]<i>Lorem</i> ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet'
console.log(string.split(/\[\w+\]/));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bd6LL/show/)